# Getting the last character in an Oracle CLOB column

Tags: oracle, substr, clob

I am having an issue with getting the last character from an Oracle CLOB column. The same SQL that works on an VARCHAR column doesn't work on a CLOB column and can't figure out why or how to make it work.

(this works in getting the last character from a VARCHAR)

**select substr(COLUMN_NAME, length(COLUMN_NAME), 1) from TABLE_NAME**

(when applied to a CLOB column, it doesn't return the last character.

**select substr(CLOB_COLUMN, length(CLOB_COLUMN), 1) from TABLE_NAME**

(Updates below)
Per Alex suggestion, I added the dump/cast and get "**Typ=1 Len=1: 10**" for that column. (I have no idea what that is)

Here is the SQL I was running:

```
set linesize 32000

select 
length(COLUMN_NAME) as clob_length, 
substr(trim(COLUMN_NAME), length(trim(COLUMN_NAME)) -50 ) as last_50,
SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME, -1) as last_char,
dump(cast(substr(COLUMN_NAME, -1) as varchar2(1)))
from TABLENAME
```

I added the SQL I used and the results for one of my rows are:

```
CLOB_LENGTH: 1227 
LAST_50: shall be permitted to be continued in service 
LAST_CHAR: 
VARCHAR2(1): Typ=1 Len=1: 10
```

(I am not clear as to what the last value means)

Comment: Can you **demonstrate** your claim for the `CLOB` column that *doesn't return the last character*? What other result do you see? Without this the question is problematic...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber See below.

Comment: Does your CLOB input contain characters like emoji (more generally, using technical terminology: characters that are encoded as "surrogate pairs" in Unicode)? If it does, that would explain what you are seeing - because Oracle uses the old UCS-2 encoding for CLOB, not UTF-16, and that messes up things like `length` computations.

Comment: Well I'd say *you* should see @brentthomas  and add the missing information of the column definition, charater set used, sample data and the wrong result...

Comment: Also please include `dump(cast(substr(clob_column, -1) as varchar2(1)))` in your query and results - from the image you linked to in a comment, it looks like that will be a newline (chr 10), or possibly whitespace. In which case it is returning the last character as it should. (But perhaps that isn't what you want to see, and you're trying to get the last letter/number/punctuation; in which case, how to get that would be a completely different question.)

Comment: @AlexPoole Does what I posted above make sense?

Comment: @brentthomas - yes, it shows what I expected. The "Typ=1 Len=1: 10" means the result of the substr is data type 1 (i.e. varchar2), length 1 byte (as it's a single simple character), and that byte has value 10 - which is the numeric code for the new line character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added the dump/cast and get "Typ=1 Len=1: 10" for that column

As suspected from [your image](https://ibb.co/CBKtQGn), your CLOB values end with new lines (character 10, which is what the dump output shows), and probably other whitespace, or perhaps line feed (character 13) if the original data came from, say, Word. That's why the 'last 50' isn't showing 50 'normal' characters - there are multiple blank lines taking up some of those positions.

If you want to ignore all of those trailing characters you can change your trim to include more characters, and apply that to both substr calls; something like:

```
substr(rtrim(clob_column, chr(32)||chr(9)||chr(10)||chr(13)), -1)
```

which will remove any combination of spaces, tabs, new lines and line feeds.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c65450ca6ba2377d31c75f9c44db116) showing the 50 character version now appears as a single line, and the last character is null, '.', 'n', 'e' etc.

Comment: Alex - What you posted shed some light on the issue and I was able to use what you posted and was able to get the "real last char" in the Blob/Clob. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Works for my simple test case:

```
SQL> create table test (col clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values ('This is a cloB');

1 row created.

SQL> select substr(col, length(col), 1) from test;

SUBSTR(COL,LENGTH(COL),1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B
```

Though, it is simpler to use `substr(col, -1)` (*take the last character*):

```
SQL> select substr(col, -1) from test;

SUBSTR(COL,-1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B
   
SQL>
```

Comment: Would it make any difference if the CLOB column had more then 1 in length?

Comment: Would it make any difference if the CLOB column had more then 1 in length?

https://ibb.co/Qb6tPCH

https://ibb.co/CBKtQGn

Comment: @brentthomas - please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70771543/edit) and add the code and output as text, not images. However, from the image, it looks like your values end in whitespace and newlines, so the last character may just be undetectable visually. Try getting `dump(substr(clob_column, -1))`, and include that output in your question too. I'm guessing it will show a newline (character 10).